# I'm trying to deploy in the digital ocean, when the final part arrives ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, digital-ocean

I'm trying to deploy in the digital ocean, when the final part arrives ~ / .rvm / bin / rvm 2.4.4 from the bundle exec rake assets: precompile
it returns this error ActiveSupport :: MessageEncryptor :: InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport :: MessageEncryptor :: InvalidMessage Who can give me a power already thank you!

```
00:06 deploy:assets:precompile
  01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.4.4 do bundle exec rake assets:precompile
  01 rake aborted!
  01 ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in `_decrypt'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:79:in `decrypt'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:42:in `read'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:271:in `method_missin…
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:433:in `secret_key_base'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:176:in `key_generator'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/globalid-0.4.1/lib/global_id/railtie.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:75:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/releases/20180606215329/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in req…
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with…
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:337:in `require_environment!'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
  01 /var/www/jrpescados/shared/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
  01 /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/bin/bundle:30:in `block in <main>'
  01 /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.4/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
  01 /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  01 /home/deploy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.4/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: We need more information. Can you run `bundle exec rake assets precompile` locally? And what about locally but using `RAILS_ENV=production` before that command?

Reading the code of the MessageEncryptor makes me beleive there is some important variable missing on your server. But maybe the asset compilation does not work at all.

Comment: When doing cap production deploy the entire process to when the bundle exec rak assets: precompile arrives, the error returns as ActiveSupport :: MessageEncryptor :: InvalidMessage:

Comment: I understand that. But I asked what happens when you run `bundle exec rake assets::precompile` locally. And what happens when you run `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered your problem and solved it.

The reason of problem is rails 5.2.0 couldn't get your `secret_key_base`. You can use `gem dotrails` in `Gemfile` and then type command in terminal at local machine: `bundle install`.

Then add `.env` to `shared/` directory at rails app of remote machine and its content is `SECRET_KEY_BASE = 'YOURSECRETKEY'`. Also add `.env` to `config/deploy.rb` file such as

```
append :linked_files, ".env"
```

Kindly reminder: add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file.

Last, deploy your app again by capistrano.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `deploy.rb` file

`before "deploy:assets:precompile", "bundle:install"`